# Scala Regex for Zero Double values

Tags: scala

I need a Scala regex to match  only for 0.0  or 0.00  or 0.000 . 
How can i achieve this ?

I have tried the below scala regex ,but it not working as expected

```
val reg = "0\\.0{1,}".r
```

This regex is always returning TRUE for all the testcases

Testcase-1: - Failed

```
val str = "0." 
val matchFound = reg.findFirstMatchIn(str).isEmpty  
matchFound: Boolean = true
```

Testcase-2: - Failed

```
val str = "0.89" 
val matchFound = reg.findFirstMatchIn(str).isEmpty  
matchFound: Boolean = true
```

Testcase-3: - Failed

```
val str = "0.abc" 
val matchFound = reg.findFirstMatchIn(str).isEmpty  
matchFound: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting your tests, I think. You test for match is empty, and get true, which means, it is always empty:

```
val reg = "0\\.0{1,}".r
val testcases = List ("0.0", "0.00", "0.000", "0.", "0.89", "0.abc")
testcases.foreach (t => println (t + ":\t" + reg.findFirstMatchIn(t).isEmpty))
0.0:    false
0.00:   false
0.000:  false
0.: true
0.89:   true
0.abc:  true
```